# How to Execute Javascript in documentdb

Tags: javascript, asp.net, azure-cosmosdb

How to execute this JS file in client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync();
its not send any result

```
function simple(UseID) {
  var collection = getContext().getCollection();


  var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
    collection.getSelfLink(),
    "SELECT * FROM c where c.id='" + UseID +"'");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to set the stored procedure response in the callback for `queryDocuments()`.

For example:

```
function simple(UseID) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();


    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        "SELECT * FROM c where c.id='" + UseID + "'",
        {},
        function(err, documents, responseOptions) {
            getContext().getResponse().setBody(documents);
        });
}
```